# Python: Delete rows from Pandas Dataframe if selected columns are empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a big `DataFrame` but I want to concentrate on a selected part of it like 3 columns out of 4. I want to remove the entire row if at least 2 of the values of these selected 3 columns are empty.

For example this is the dataframe I have and my selected columns are `['B','C','D']`:

```
 A   B   C   D
     1       1
 2           2
 3   3   3   3
 4
```

How to get rid of the rows if at least two of values are empty in the selected columns, which are second and fourth rows.

Final dataframe is:

```
 A   B   C   D
     1       1
 3   3   3   3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `subset` with `thresh` on `dropna`

```
In [2720]: df.dropna(subset=['B','C','D'], thresh=2)
Out[2720]:
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
2  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
```

Or, use `notnull`

```
In [2723]: df[df[['B', 'C', 'D']].notnull().sum(1).ge(2)]
Out[2723]:
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
2  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
```

---

Details

```
In [2722]: df
Out[2722]:
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  2.0
2  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
3  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

If the values are blanks instead of null, use `df[df[['B', 'C', 'D']].eq('').sum(1).lt(2)]` or `df[df[['B', 'C', 'D']].ne('').sum(1).ge(2)]`

Answer (score 6):

Use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) if empty values are `NaN`s:

```
cols = ['B','C','D']

df = df.dropna(subset=cols, thresh=2)
#same as
#df = df[df[cols].isnull().sum(1) < 2]
print (df)
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
2  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
```

Or if empty values are empty strings compare numpy arrays created by `values` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[(df[cols].values == '').sum(axis=1) < 2]
```

Comment: if I use this function it takes account of all columns, maybe my example is misleading.

Comment: I have a really big dataframe bu I want to check this condition on selected columns and delete the entire row accordingly.